# No value given for the required parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run the qry below against an access database and I get an error No value Given for the required parameter?

```
SELECT        ID, DateColumn, Less90, Between90180, Between180365, GreaterThan365, SUM(Less90) + SUM(Between90180) + SUM(Between180365) + SUM(GreaterThan365) 
                     AS Total, SUM(Between180365) / Total AS Expr1,
                         (SELECT        SUM(Between180365) / (SUM(Less90) + SUM(Between90180) + SUM(Between180365) + SUM(GreaterThan365))
                           FROM            tblHandpieceFaliuresAge T2
                           WHERE        T2.ID <= tblHandpieceFaliuresAge.ID) AS RunningSum
FROM            tblHandpieceFaliuresAge
GROUP BY ID, DateColumn, Less90, Between90180, Between180365, GreaterThan365
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have typed one of your columns incorrectly, and Access thinks you are trying to pass a parameter.

Go over your field names again and make sure they have all been entered correctly.

I believe the problem may be this:

```
SUM(Less90) + SUM(Between90180) + SUM(Between180365) + SUM(GreaterThan365) 
                 AS Total
```

And then you refer to it later as `Total` here:

```
SUM(Between180365) / Total
```

Access can't take the alias and re-use it in the query, you need this:

```
SUM(Between180365) / 
    (SUM(Less90) + SUM(Between90180) + SUM(Between180365) + SUM(GreaterThan365))
```

Also make sure you handle the denominator so you don't divide by zero.

Comment: I also reckon that is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The usual cause for this is that you have misspelled one of the field names, and, thus, Access thinks it is a parameter (which is not specified).

There are two ways to fix this:

- Manually check evey field name, to make sure it is spelled correctly or
- start removing fields from your query until the problem disappears. The last field removed is the culprit.