# VBA obtaining a SUM of values from MS Access, returns error: No Value Given For One or More Parameter

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have the following code to retrieve a sum out of an access field.
keep getting the error "No Value Given For One or More Parameter". I'm assuming its something simple. I tried looking up the syntax and google appears to give me what i already have. Appreciate your help.

**EDIT**

```
Public Sub sum()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim countfrmdb As String
Dim currentmth As String
currentmth = Sheets("Data").Range("f3")  'this has been formatted to get the month name. e.g: Jan. Thats how its in my database.

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=data.mdb"
strSql = "SELECT SUM(field_name) As Total FROM Table_name WHERE field_month_name = " & currentmth

cn.Open strConnection
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
countfrmdb = rs.Fields(0)
MsgBox (countfrmdb)
```

Comment: I assume that line is `Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)` but can you get exactly what line it is happening on?

Comment: @Newd correct. the error points to Set rs = cn... so i was assuming my SUM syntax is incorrect.?

Comment: From everything that I see you syntax in the SQL is correct.

Comment: @Newd I know right! I havent been able to figure why i am getting this error then. do you want me to post the entire code?

Comment: Create a new query in Access query designer.  Switch it to SQL View.  Paste in your `SELECT` statement and try to run the query.  What is the name of the parameter?

Comment: Your syntax, as displayed, is correct. You have obfuscated your code so we don't know what you are *really* doing. Please [edit] your question to show us the actual SQL statement you are trying to execute.

Comment: What is the data type of `field_name`

Comment: @HansUp I ran the select statement in sql viewer and it gave me the correct sum! so weird. the same code doesnt execute correctly in the vba module

Comment: @GordThompson I have added the complete code in my post. apologies, i didnt add everything because i didnt want to complicate the question and added only the problem statement.

Comment: @marv is your field name actually field_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated *currentmth* is a text value containing the current month.  So when you add *currentmth* to the `WHERE` clause without enclosing it in quotes, the db engine thinks *Jan* is the name of a parameter instead of a text value.

Change this ...

```sql
WHERE field_month_name = " & currentmth
```

to this ...

```sql
WHERE field_month_name = '" & currentmth & "'"
```

A good way to troubleshoot these type of issues is to examine the actual text of the SQL statement you're asking Access to execute.  `Debug.Print` is useful for that purpose.

```sql
strSql = "SELECT SUM(field_name) As Total FROM Table_name WHERE field_month_name = " & currentmth
Debug.Print strSql
```

You can then view the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window.  And you can copy the statement text from there and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.  Or you can show us the actual statement text which is producing the error your reported.

Comment: you rocked it my man. i know it had to do something with the blimming syntx. thank you for your help!!

Comment: not sure if i can ask one more question. the table contains blank fields and now i'm getting "Invalid use of NULL" error.! can you help?

Comment: Neither the `Sum()` expression nor the `WHERE` clause you showed us could possibly trigger "Invalid use of Null".  Therefore I'm positive you have still not shown us the actual SQL statement which triggers that error.  Submit a new question with the actual statement text and include the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the information found here: [No value given for the required parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283242/no-value-given-for-the-required-parameter) I would say that your Field_Name or table_name aren't correctly spelled.  You can test this by purposefully putting in the wrong field name and you will get the same error you are getting.

Comment: I triple checked the spellings and didnt find anything wrong. I hope i am not over reading things and missing something simple. I hope you can help me again from my complete code post above.

Comment: Almost certainly what HansUp said is the cause.  Though you might want to change your naming scheme ;-)