# Dapper, MS Access, Integers and "no value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, oledb, dapper

I keep getting the error "no value given for one or more required parameters" on the third attempt to insert in the code below. The first two attempts work fine. I'm running in .NET 4.0, against MS Access in VS 2012. And this problem appears to be consistent whether I'm using a 2007 accdb or a 2000-2003 mdb. I'm using the following code to test:

```
using Dapper;

using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace DapperTest {
    class Program {
        static string accdb = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=W:\Projects\CSharp\DapperTest\DuhData.accdb;";
        static string mdb = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=W:\Projects\CSharp\DapperTest\DuhData.mdb";

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var dis = new DisMember { FName = "Heza", LName = "Dufus", Initials = "", HighestGrade = 1 };

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(mdb)) {
                try {
                    conn.Execute("DROP TABLE DisMember;");
                }
                catch (System.Exception) { }

                conn.Execute("CREATE TABLE DisMember ( "
                            +     "FName CHAR, "
                            +     "Initials CHAR, "
                            +     "LName CHAR, "
                            +     "HighestGrade Number "
                            + "); "
                );

                // First attempt: This works in Dapper but does not include HighestGrade
                conn.Execute( "INSERT INTO DisMember(FName, Initials, LName) "
                            + "VALUES (@FName, @Initials, @LName);", dis
                            );

                // Second attempt: This works without Dapper and includes HighestGrade
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DisMember(FName, Initials, LName, HighestGrade) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); ";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", dis.FName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Initials", dis.Initials);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LName", dis.LName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HighestGrade", 1);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                // Third attempt: This does not work with Dapper because of HighestGrade
                conn.Execute("INSERT INTO DisMember(FName, Initials, LName, HighestGrade) "
                            + "VALUES (@FName, @Initials, @LName, @HighestGrade);", dis
                            );
            }
        }
    }

    public class DisMember {
        public DisMember( ) { }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Initials { get; set; }
        public int HighestGrade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, is this a bug in Dapper? OleDB? Access 2013? Or something else?

Any and all clues  greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make HighestGrade  an integer in Database?

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but this is (ultimately) against existing data. I have to deal with it as it currently is. :)

Comment: Then make HighestGrade a floating point in your class definition!!! Or perform some conversion.

Comment: Another good thing to try, but... it results in the exact same error... :(

Comment: Was the problem just an error in the SQL? Is it the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283242/no-value-given-for-the-required-parameter ?

Comment: No, that's a different error. This was a bug in Dapper. Notice, in my answer, that I ordered the columns alphabetically and this fixed the issue. In my original version, HighestGrade, when I moved it to the position that was alphabetically between FName and LName, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. Playing a hunch on another answer I found elsewhere that indicated there was a bug in Dapper that had to do with the order of the columns/parameters, I modified the code alphabetically like this:

```
conn.Execute( "INSERT INTO DisMember(FName, HighestGrade, Initials, LName) "
            + "VALUES (@FName, @HighestGrade, @Initials, @LName);", dis
            );
```

And it works. According to the article I found, this bug had been fixed in Dapper, but... apparently not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was mistaken about it being a bug in Dapper. It's a problem with MS Access.