# No value given for one or more required parameters on Access Db join query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am using `OleDB` provider to sync MS Access DB in C# programming. I got an error while using join query. Here is my code

```sql
SELECT BRC.*, Pdata.*, Contact.* 
FROM ((BookingBRCTbl as BRC 
LEFT JOIN PDataTbl as PData on BRC.PID = PData.PID) 
LEFT JOIN PractitionerTbl as Contact on PData.PatGp = Contact.GPID)
```

And i got error like `No value given for one or more required parameters`. What should i do? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance you can format that in a more readable format?

Comment: This error means that some of names in SQL text wrong. Check names or build the query in query builder instead of manual text editing. Also remove `access` and `mysql` tags from question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No value given for the required parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283242/no-value-given-for-the-required-parameter)